# Por qué este código y me arroja Error: unexpected symbol in "df?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
     library(readxl)
     df=read_xlsx(path="TNAPRIM.xlsx")
     a=as.double(df$a)
     b=as.double(df$b)
     c=as.double(df$c)
    d=as.double(df$d)
    e=as.double(df$e)
    df_colum=as.vector(append(append(append(append(a,b),c),d),e))
    agno = append(append(append(append( rep(c(2000), each=130),  rep(c(2005), each=130)),                 rep(c(2011), each=130)),  rep(c(2015), each=130)), rep(c(2017), each=130))
    genero=rep(c("m","f"),times=325)
    region = rep (c("Tarapacá", "Tarapacá", "Antofagasta", "Antofagasta", "Atacama", "Atacama", "Coquimbo", "Coquimbo", "°Valparaíso", "Valparaíso", "Rancagua", "Rancagua", "Maule", "Maule",  "Concepción", "Concepción", "Araucanía", "Araucanía", "Los_Lagos", "Los_Lagos", "Aysen", "Aysen",    "Antantica", "Antartica","Metorpolitana", "Metropolitana"), times=65)
     **df <- data.frame(region = region, genero=genero, agno=agno,asistencia=df_colum)region**
```

Al ejecutar la última línea me arroja error.

No sé porque, puesto que es igual a otro código que realicé al cual solamente cambié una variable.
Si me pueden colaborar, lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola, esto es asp o python? Si es python, podrías por favor [edit] la pregunta y poner la etiqueta correcta además de tu código indentado como lo tienes tú? Ahora mismo no nos es posible replicar el problema porque no va a ejecutarse debido a esto. Lo otro: podrías incluir EN la pregunta el mensaje completo de error, por favor? Gracias